# File restore from MVC4 compile files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, compilation

I have my all compile files project in MVC4 on my IIS repertory.
I lost the all project file.

Is it possible to get project in Visual Studio open from compile files ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you checked the Backup Files Folder of Visual Studio if your files are there?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find the VS Project Files, you will need a *decompiler* to produce the C# files you need from the binary DLL's you have (decompiles the IL produced at compile time) . Please be aware the code files in some instances wont match exactly.

### **Free Decompilers**

- [JetBrains Dotpeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)
- [ILspy](http://ilspy.net/)

### **Paid Decompilers**

- [Redgate
  Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

There may be many more out there. But you are looking for **.NET Compilers.**